# axios interceptor - hold off the request until cookie API call is finished, and only then continue

Tags: javascript, cookies, promise, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to get the axios to wait until one extra call in the interceptor finishes. So I am using NuxtJS as a frontend SPA and API in Laravel 8.

I've tried a lot of different things over the course of last ~ 4 days but nothing seems to be working.

**THE GOAL**

I need my axios REQUEST interceptor to check for existence of the cookie. If cookie is not present I need to make an API call first to grab the cookie and then we can continue with any other request.

**WHAT I AM DOING?**

So basically I have Axios interceptor for the requests that will call cookie endpoint if the cookie doesn't exist.

I am also saving cookie request promise to be reused in case there are multiple calls and the cookie still is not there.

**PROBLEM**

While it was supposed to just call cookie API first and everything else after I am mostly getting two results in different variations of the attached code.

A) I am making an extra cookie call but it is not in the required order so I still end up hitting laravel endpoint multiple times without cookies which causes extra sessions to spawn.

B) It is not making any calls at all (attached example).

Does anyone know what in the world I am confusing here?

```js
export default function ({$axios, redirect, $cookiz, store}) {
  $axios.onRequest(async request => {
    // make sure that XSRF cookie exists before we make aby calls to prevent backend from
    // creating multiple session when page on load calls more than one endpoint, if we don't have
    // that cookie we will first have to get it and then call the rest of the endpoints
    const xsrfCookie = $cookiz.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    if (xsrfCookie === undefined || xsrfCookie === null || xsrfCookie === '') {
      await store.dispatch('login/getXsrfCookie')
      $axios.request(request)
    }
    $axios.request(request)
  })
}
```

```js
  getXsrfCookie(context) {
    if (context.state.xsrfCookiePromise instanceof Promise) {
      return context.state.xsrfCookiePromise
    }
    const xsrfCookiePromise = this.$axios.get('/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      context.commit('setXsrfCookiePromise', null)
      console.log('This is the cookie response', response)
    })
    context.commit('setXsrfCookiePromise', xsrfCookiePromise)

    return context.state.xsrfCookiePromise
  }
```

Comment: Two things I see looking at your code: 1- you should return the config inside onRequest helper when it's async, reason [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/482#issuecomment-967145440)  2- seems that you are using axios to get the cookie too, doesn't it ends up in a infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about nuxt, and have only a vague idea about axios interceptors, but just looking at the code...

- I think you want to persist a cookie, not the promise for a cookie.
- I don't think you need to involve the store.
- I think you can do that with your cookie plugin. If I'm right about that, using the `set` method is what you need. (you might need an options param, described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt))

```
async getXsrfCookie() {
  if (!$cookiz.get('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    // the op should double check which part of the response to persist, whether to stringify it, etc.
    const response = await this.$axios.get('/csrf-cookie');
    $cookiz.set('XSRF-TOKEN', response.data);
  }
}
      
export default function ({$axios, redirect, $cookiz, store}) {
  $axios.onRequest(async request => {
    await getXsrfCookie();
    return $axios.request(request)
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. I think you misunderstood. I don't have the problem with setting the cookies. Browser does that on its own. Cookie call Promise is stored so I don't have to call cookie endpoint multiple times. If another call fires I will just attach it to the back of existing cookie promise. All I need is a way to fire cookie request first and make other requests wait until cookie one is over. That should happen always when cookie for whatever reason is missing.

Comment: So to calrify the waiting part is the problem. That's what is a bit problematic for me.